# Product of two natural numbers is also natural.

Tags: induction, solution-verification

Is this correct proof using **induction** that product of two natural numbers $n, m$ is also natural?
We assume that $n = 1$.
$mn = m·1 = m$.
We suppose that $n$ is a natural number and that $m*n$ is a natural number.   We must prove that $m(n + 1)$ is a natural number.
$m(n + 1) = mn + m$, which is a sum of two natural numbers, and is therefore a natural number(already proved).

Comment: You could also establish (by induction) that the sum of *several* naturals is a natural. The main claim follows immediately.

Comment: It is, if you have proven the distributive law (or taken it as an axiom) and have proven the sum of natural numbers is natural.  Have you proven both of those?  Any class that asks you to prove this without taking it as an axiom isn't likely to have distributive law or closure of the naturals under addition as givens.

Comment: What class it this for and how were the natural numbers established and what is the definition of addition and multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this prove is correct. Make sure to mention in the beginning that you pick $m$ as an arbitrary natural number. Since then you get the result that the multiplication of ANY two natural numbers is a natural number. Also don't forget to address the zero element (if you consider that to be a natural number).

Answer (score 2):

Well, one can define addition and multiplication as follows:

$m+0=m, ~m\cdot 1 = m$

$m+n' = (m+n)', ~m\cdot n' = m\cdot n+m$

where $n'$ is the successor of $n$ defined by the injective mapping $n\mapsto n'$ with $0$ not in the image set.

Using induction on $n$, it's clear that both operations are well-defined.